# Setting the `textSize` in sp to `textView` does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, dpi

I'm trying to set the `textSize` in sp to `textView` to be seen correctly on all devices. This is my code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

On a low resolution device the text is like this:
    [image]
On a medium  resolution device the text is like this:
    [image]
On a high resolution device the text is like this:
    [image]

I need that text to be seen correctly on all devices. I tried to use `android:textSize="30dp"` but same result. Where am i wrong? Thnaks!

Comment: How did you get that screen shots?

Comment: From the emulator using the Snipping Tool.

Comment: I guess they are been scaled, the rest of the UI is downscaled too

Comment: Ok, but how can i fix this?

Comment: You don't have nothing to fix, they are scaled to fit your screen conserving the aspect ratio.

Look. The first one and the last one have almost the same width. Open and Image editor and scale them to the real device size.

Comment: And what are you trying to say is that on real device, the text will be displayed correctly?

Comment: Yes. The first screen shot is from a low dpi device but it has a width of 800 pixel. There is no real device with that size and low desinty

Comment: I will try to do this on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Indicating a size using sp is also affected by the font preference on a device.  A device with a larger font preference vs. a device with a smaller font preference displaying a line of text with the same sp is going to look different.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what is all about. How can i fix this? In a real case scenario, on a real device, will work?

Answer (score 0):

30 sp is a currect value for devices. that means when you use sp , all devices changing size with our device resolotion. if you want see the same result for textview in all of device you can use px or dp in your application.

> ***Important***: **PX** **or** **DP** is not good result for all devices.then you should use sp for
>   **textview**.